# How can I join some values in rows to be value columns in a dataset/association

Tags: dataset, associations

```
{<|"date" -> "2016-04-12", "key" -> 1, 
 "1st" -> 0.9652777777777778`, "2nd" -> 0.8867924528301887`, "3rd" -> 0.49074074074074076`|>,
 <|"date" -> "2016-04-12", "key" -> 2, 
 "2nd" -> 0.14619883040935672`, "3rd" -> 0.15212981744421908`|>,
 <|"date" -> "2016-04-13" , "key" -> 1, 
 "2nd" -> 0.14619883040935672`, "3rd" -> 0.15212981744421908`|>,
 <|"date" -> "2016-04-13" , "key" -> 2, 
 "2nd" -> 0.14619883040935672`, "3rd" -> 0.15212981744421908`|>
} // Dataset
```

Consider we are constructing a feature dataset for an id[product,user]. Feature is time related, like action_behavior, and we need some feature for a user in a period.

Should I do this in a `Association` structure? since we have `JoinAcross`? not a `Dataset` structure?

The example shows that `"key"` `1` has feature in `04-12` and feature in `04-13`. What I want to do is, when I get data from hive, to construct this kind of tables

select a.key,a.1_st,a.2_st,b.1_st,b.2_st from
    select 
    a.key
    a.1_st
    a.2_st
    from table_1 where date='date' a 
    left outer join
    b.key
    b.1_st
    b.2_st
    where date='date-1' b
    on a.key1=b.key2

I mean the result table is one dataset only, and there are many dates rows beside `2016-04-12, 2016-04-13`:

[image]

Comment: But what is a query input, a date or a period of time?

Comment: @Kuba [a date+a period time], if just last day, then a date is enough

Answer (score 4):

`Dataset` excels at representing hierarchical data.  If you look at your problem as creating a hierarchy of records with levels `"key"` and `"date"` then a `Dataset` solution quickly presents itself.

To make querying easier I first ensure all records contain all keys with `KeyUnion`.  Then create the `Dataset`.

```
dat = Dataset@KeyUnion@associations
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now with `GroupBy` a single hierarchical `Dataset` can be created.

```
gdat = dat[GroupBy[#"key" &], GroupBy[#"date" &]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is kind of difficult to see the structure so we can implicitly use `Dataset` to show it. **Note** *this is only needed to show the structure in a visually friendly way.*  You don't need to do this on your larger dataset.

```
gdat[All, Dataset, Dataset]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you can query the hierarchical dataset for your values.

```
gdat[1, All, All, "1st"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
gdat[All, "2016-04-12", All, "3rd"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
gdat[2, "2016-04-12"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And so on.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can be done using `JoinAcross`.

```
associations = {
   <|"date" -> "2016-04-12", "key" -> 1, "1st" -> 0.9652777777777778`, 
    "2nd" -> 0.8867924528301887`, "3rd" -> 0.49074074074074076`|>,
   <|"date" -> "2016-04-12", "key" -> 2,
    "2nd" -> 0.14619883040935672`, "3rd" -> 0.15212981744421908`|>,
   <|"date" -> "2016-04-13", "key" -> 1,
    "2nd" -> 0.14619883040935672`, "3rd" -> 0.15212981744421908`|>,
   <|"date" -> "2016-04-13", "key" -> 2,
    "2nd" -> 0.14619883040935672`, "3rd" -> 0.15212981744421908`|>};

Dataset[associations]
```

[image]

```
dates = Flatten@Values[Union@KeyTake[associations, "date"]];

Dataset /@ Map[Function[date, Select[#["date"] == date &]@associations], dates]
```

[image]

Comment: An alternative: `Dataset /@ GatherBy[associations, #date &]`.

Comment: There is a problem to join two dataset into one, I've update my pic.

Comment: @Xavier hi, GatherBy/GroupBy just split is a thread, and then should filter by dates, and to join the results. See my updated picture. consider the situation, there are 10 dates, and for a specific date, I just want the right part is the last date's data in the right part.

Comment: @HyperGroups Will the dates given in the list of associations always be ordered? Are you dealing always with 2 keys `"keys"` for each date, or can you have any number of it?